# Pass C++ object (with possible multiple virtual inheritance) through a C ABI via void pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have some concerns about the safety of type conversions I'm designing an abstract interface, witch will be supported by plugins exporting an object orientated C ABI, i.e. pointers to objects and C-style functions of the form `func(void *this, ...)` rather than C++ style member functions these will then be packed into a struct representing the objects implementation. However some of my underlying frameworks, use multiple virtual inheritance.

Simplified example

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void doA()
}

class B
{
    public:
        virtual void doB()
}

class C : public A, public B
{
    public:
        virtual void doA()
        virtual void doB()
}

struct impA
{
    (*doA)(void *self);
}

struct impB
{
    (*doB)(void *self);
}

struct impC
{
    (*doA)(void *self);
    (*doB)(void *self);
}

void * AfromC(void *v) {
    C*c = reinterpret_cast<C*>(v); // Known to be C* type
    return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(c)); // method 1
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(c)); // method 2

    //method 3 & 4
    C** c = static_cast<C**>(v); // Known to be C* type
    return static_cast<void*>(&static_cast<A*>(*c)); // method 3
    return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A**>(c)); // method 4
}

/////////// main code

class A
{
    public:
        void doA() { imp.doA(self); }
    private:
        impA imp;
        void *self;
}

class B
{
    public:
        void doB() { imp.doB(self); }
    private:
        impB imp;
        void *self;
}
```

Consider AfromC, I have 4 possible methods of getting a pointer that I can safely pass through a C ABI, I want to known the consideration for these different methods, my preference would be method 1.

I'm not sure if all these methods are legal or safe.

Note: Object will always be access by functions in the binary from which they are created/destroyed they return/accept other objects handled by them self or C-style data types (up to structs of POD)

While I've found mention of such things on the net, they are all about people having problems as a result of converting to void i.e. `A* a= static_cast<A*>(static_cast<void*>(c)) // c -> C*` which is to be expected as this doesn't correct the vtable and the solutions is to use the abstract base type (this wron't work for me as I need to pass through the C ABI), however I've also heard mention of virtual pointers being larger than normal pointers hence my reason for considering methods 3 and 4, as this would be a normal pointer to the larger pointer and thus safe even for types with larger pointers.

So my main question is will method 1 work with out problem? Aslo could I safely define a template function along the lines of `template  <typename T, typename U> void * void_cast(U v) { static_cast<void *>(static_cast<T>(v)); }` to simplify plugin code. Finally if method 1 is correct why? and can any of the methods be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that you can convert back and forth from a pointer to object to a pointer to its base class, and from a pointer to object to a `void *`. But there are no guarantees that all those pointers keep same value (nor even same representation)!

Said differently with examples where C is derived from A:

```
C* c = new C;
A* a = static_cast<A*>(c);   // legal
C* c1 = static_cast<C*>(a);  // ok c1 == c guaranteed

void *vc = static_cast<void *>(c); // legal
C* c2 = static_cast<C*>(vc); // ok, c2 == c guaranteed

void *va = static_cast<void *>(a); // legal, but va == vc is not guaranteed

a2 = static_cast<A*>(vc);    // legal, but a2 == a not guaranteed 
                             //  and dereferencing a2 is Undefined Behaviour
```

That means that if `v` is built as `void *v = static_cast<void *>(c)`;  and then passed to your `AfromC` method `static_cast<A*>(v)` may not point to a valid object. And both methods (1) and (2) are no-op because you cast from `void*` to a pointer to obj and back which is required to get original value.

For method (4), but you cast a pointer to void to a pointer to pointer, from pointer to pointer to pointer to pointer again and then back to void. As 3.9.2 Compound types [basic.compound] declares:

> 3 ...Pointers to layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and
>   alignment requirements...

As all pointers are *layout compatible types*, the second operation should not change the value and we are back in the no-op of method (1) and (2)

Method (3) should not even compile, because you take the address of a static_cast and that is not a lvalue.

TL/DR: methods (1), (2) and (4) are no-op, meaning that you return the input value unchanged and method (3) is illegal because `&` operator requires a lvalue.

The only realiable way to convert a void* pointing to a C object to something that could be safely converted to a A* is:

```
void * AfromC(void *v) {
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(v);   // v shall be static_cast<void>(ptr_to_C)
    A* a = static_cast<A*>(c);
    return static_cast<void *>(a); // or return a; with the implicit void * convertion
}
```

or as a single line expression

```
void * AfromC(void *v) {
    return static_cast<A*>(static_cast<C*>(v));
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify "but va == vc is not guaranteed" given I cast va to a as A* = static_cast<A*>(va), could I then cast this to an object of type C i.e. either static_cast<C*>(a) or reinterpret_cast<C*>(a), given I know that va had been converted as in your answer from an object of type C, or would this no longer be safe after casting through the void type?

Comment: "dereferencing a2 is Undefined Behaviour" care to explain why you think this? From what I can tell, in a generic view `a2` and `c2` are derived identically from `a` and `c` so they should be equally UB - either yes or no, not halfway.

Comment: @glenflet: No guarantee for that can be found in standard. And in implementations using vtables for virtual functions, it is common that the address of the object is the address of the vtable. In that case, the static_cast does the offset correction, but the actual value of `va` and `vc` are different in that case. Just try with a debugger and base- and sub-classes having virtual functions

Comment: @dascandy: `va` is built through a static cast from a pointer to derived. In common implementations, `vc` and `c` will have same representation and value, but `va` and `vc` will have different values if A and C all have virtual functions. As `va2` if built from a `void *` it will have same value as `vc` so it could not point to a valid object. That's why dereferencing it would be UB.

Comment: @SergeBallesta if you build `a2` from `va` and that from `a`, then it's from a T* to void* to T*. No UB in sight - and `a2` won't need to be equal to `vc` at all. Oh wait, you're casting from `vc` to `a2`... no, that's UB.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(v)); // method 1
> return reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<A*>(v)); // method 2
> ```

If `void* v` points to an instance of type `C`, then `static_cast<A*>(v)` is wrong.

> ```
> //method 3 & 4
> C** c = static_cast<C**>(v); // Known to be C* type
> return static_cast<void*>(&static_cast<A*>(*c)); // method 3
> return static_cast<void*>(static_cast<A**>(c)); // method 4
> ```

If `void* v` points to an instance of type `C`, then `static_cast<C**>(v)` is wrong.

---

Be very careful about casting `void*` into the correct type of the pointed object. I would prefer to use `static_cast` when I can, instead of `reinterpret_cast`. I also prefer to implicit casts for base subobject access and for conversion to `void*`. The reduced boilerplate is less straining to the eyes.

```
void* AfromC(void* v) {
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(v); // Known to be C* type
    A* a = c;                  // point to base sub object
    return a;                  // implicit conversion to void*
}
```